# Why was my suggested edit, which formatted the HTML of the question, rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19141928) is my suggested edit. Reviewers say:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service,
>   or is deliberately destructive.

But I just formatted the HTML code.

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted it formatted, as it would defeat the entire purpose of the question.

Comment: @JoeC is it possible? OP did not reject the question.

Answer (score 26):

If someone posts HTML code on the website because they're asking a question about HTML/css/JavaScript or anything that has to do with the HTML code, you should **not** convert that code into formatted text. You should leave it as is.

That edit is destructive, and will make the question harder to understand and answer. It is properly rejected.

Comment: The problem is the code is no longer properly indented, thus converted to formatted text. Look at it outside of markdown view and you'll see it's destructive

Comment: [Voting on meta is different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work/47635#47635) @RohamTehrani